# Magento Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I have created a custom module in backend and also in front end.
I have given everything correctly but still i am getting fatal error : Call to a member function load() on a non-object.

My config.xml file:

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config>
    <modules>
<Blazedream_VendorComplaints>
  <version>0.1.0</version>
</Blazedream_VendorComplaints>
</modules>
<frontend>
 <routers>
  <vendorcomplaints>
    <use>standard</use>
      <args>
        <module>Blazedream_VendorComplaints</module>
        <frontName>vendorcomplaints</frontName>
      </args>
  </vendorcomplaints>
  </routers>
<layout>
      <updates>
        <vendorcomplaints>
           <file>vendorcomplaints.xml</file>
        </vendorcomplaints>
      </updates>
  </layout>
 </frontend>
 <global>
  <helpers>
  <vendorcomplaints>
    <class>Blazedream_VendorComplaints_Helper</class>
  </vendorcomplaints>
  </helpers>
  <blocks>
  <vendorcomplaints>
    <class>Blazedream_VendorComplaints_Block</class>
  </vendorcomplaints>
  </blocks>
  <models>
  <vendorcomplaints>
    <class>Blazedream_VendorComplaints_Model</class>
    <resourceModel>VendorComplaints_mysql4</resourceModel>
  </vendorcomplaints>
  <vendorcomplaints_mysql4>
    <class>Blazedream_VendorComplaints_Model_Mysql4</class>
    <entities>        
          <complaints>
            <table>vendor_complaints</table>
          </complaints>
    </entities>
  </vendorcomplaints_mysql4>
 </models>
 <resources>
  <vendorcomplaints_setup>
    <setup>
      <module>Blazedream_VendorComplaints</module>
    </setup>
    <connection>
      <use>core_setup</use>
    </connection>
  </vendorcomplaints_setup>
  <vendorcomplaints_write>
    <connection>
      <use>core_write</use>
    </connection>
  </vendorcomplaints_write>
  <vendorcomplaints_read>
    <connection>
      <use>core_read</use>
    </connection>
  </vendorcomplaints_read>
</resources>
 </global>
 <admin>
<routers>
  <vendorcomplaints>
    <use>admin</use>
    <args>
      <module>Blazedream_VendorComplaints</module>
      <frontName>vendorcomplaints</frontName>
    </args>
  </vendorcomplaints>
 </routers>
 </admin>
 <adminhtml>
 <menu>
 <marketplace>
    <children>
         <complaints module="vendorcomplaints">
        <title>Manage Complaints</title>
        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
        <action>vendorcomplaints/adminhtml_complaints</action>
      </complaints>
    </children>
 </marketplace>
 </menu>
 <acl>
    <resources>
        <all>
        <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <complaints>
                    <title>Complaints Module</title>
                    <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                </complaints>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
<layout>
  <updates>
    <vendorcomplaints>
      <file>vendorcomplaints.xml</file>
    </vendorcomplaints>
  </updates>
 </layout>
 </adminhtml>
 </config>
```

My model files:  local/Blazedream/VendorComplaints/Model/Complaints.php

```
             <?php

     class Blazedream_VendorComplaints_Model_Complaints extends  Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
     {
protected function _construct(){

   $this->_init("vendorcomplaints/complaints");

 }

}
```

local/Blazedream/VendorComplaints/Model/Mysql4/Complaints.php

```
       <?php
     class Blazedream_VendorComplaints_Model_Mysql4_Complaints extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
 {
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init("vendorcomplaints/complaints", "vendor_complaints_id");
}
 }
```

local/Blazedream/VendorComplaints/Model/Mysql4/Complaints/Collection.php

```
           <?php
  class Blazedream_VendorComplaints_Model_Mysql4_Complaints_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
{

    public function _construct(){
        $this->_init("vendorcomplaints/complaints");
    }
}
```

My sql setup file:local/Blazedream/VendorComplaints/sql/vendorcomplaints_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php

```
           <?php
       $installer = $this;
       $installer->startSetup();
       $sql=<<<SQLTEXT
       create table vendor_complaints(vendor_complaints_id int not null  auto_increment,name varchar(1000) not null,order_id varchar(100) NOT NULL,email_id varchar(100) not null,reason text,customer_group varchar(100) not null, primary key(vendor_complaints_id));
     SQLTEXT;
     $installer->run($sql);
     $installer->endSetup();
```

I really dont know where i have done the mistakes.

Can anyone help me to find the issue???

Comment: Have you called the model like $model = Mage::getModel('vendorcomplaints/complaints');

Comment: Yes I have called like that only.

Comment: Actually I am not getting the grid also. I got only add item tab. If i click on that then I am getting fatal error.

Comment: I think you don't have a setup class e.g. Blazedream_VendorComplaints_Model_Mysql4_Setup which should extend Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup and you should add this class in config.xml.

Comment: I found the problem in my code. Actually i did not give my <action> tag function correctly. That was the problem. Now, I have corrected it.

Comment: My sql setup was wrong. I have corrected it.. Now it is working fine. Thanks to all, Who helped to fix the issue.